# Updating an automated Xcode build script to use exportPlist file instead of -exportFormat

Tags: kivy, xcode9, xcodebuild, buildozer

I'm using an automated build tool called buildozer to automate the build of an iOS app and the tool hasn't been updated in awhile.  One of the issues that hasn't been resolved is that still uses old commands like -export format.

```
    self.buildozer.info('Creating archive...')
    self.buildozer.cmd((
            '/usr/bin/xcodebuild'
            ' -alltargets'
            ' -configuration {mode}'
            ' -scheme {scheme}'
            ' -archivePath "{xcarchive}"'
            ' archive'
            ' ENABLE_BITCODE=NO'
        ).format(mode=mode, xcarchive=xcarchive, scheme=app_name.lower()),
        cwd=build_dir)

    self.buildozer.info('Creating IPA...')
    self.buildozer.cmd((
            '/usr/bin/xcodebuild'
            ' -exportArchive'
            ' -exportFormat IPA'
            ' -archivePath "{xcarchive}"'
            ' -exportPath "{ipa}"'
            ' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY={ioscodesign}'
            ' ENABLE_BITCODE=NO'
        ).format(xcarchive=xcarchive, ipa=ipa_tmp, ioscodesign=ioscodesign),
        cwd=build_dir)
```

One of the issues I'm having from a little digging is that the archive command should create an exportOptions plist file (maybe the archive command needs updated parameters too?) but I can't find any export plist files anywhere to call after the archive command finishes.

Heres the full code https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/master/buildozer/targets/ios.py

Answer (score 0):

Unlocking the iPhone that was connected to my Mac fixed the issue with plist file being generated.